# Confusion to add custom fonts in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

I know how to add custom fonts in the app. But confusion in `weight` and `style`.

For Ex.

If I'm adding `Montserrat` font in the app and In my app's **asset** folder has is only **`Montserrat-Regular.ttf`**  So in **pubspec.yaml** file I wrote.

```
 fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: asset/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
```

And in the `Text` widgets I used all the 3 normal, bold and italic and it's working!!!

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'This is normal font',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              'This is bold font',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              'This is italic font',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

So If **regular** font will work for bold and italic then in the [Official tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) Why adding

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

**Raleway-Italic.ttf** and **RobotoMono-Bold.ttf** ???? They should have add only **regular** fonts in asset and it could work I think?

And another things In my above code. if I set

- 1st Text "fontWeight: FontWeight.w300"
- 2st Text "fontWeight: FontWeight.w500"

I can not find any difference.

> OR

if I set

- 1st Text "fontWeight: FontWeight.w600"
- 2st Text "fontWeight: FontWeight.w900"

I can not find any difference.

Why, one will explain me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a font with variants (diferents fonts from italic or Bold/Medium) you can define them in the same font family:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf
          style: italic
          weight: 100
```

In my Roboto exemple:

If you use the font family Roboto and a text with default weight it will use the Roboto-Regular.ttf

But if you use the italic style it will use the Roboto-Italic.ttf

I have variations to BOLD, MEDIUM, THIN and each ITALIC form.

It makes the font be more polish than the font that were software styled...

In the `pubspec.yaml` file, you have `fonts` that can have one or more children `- family` that can have one or more children `fonts` (for variants that works exactly the way that works in css `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`).

`fonts` can have one or more children of `- asset` and it can have `weight` and/or `style` as children or none.

Comment: If I want to use Roboto-Thin font then should I make another family asset? like -

fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf
    - family: RobotoThin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact question. Flutter doesn't even need an italic .otf to render an italic styled text. This is very confusing. So I took sometime to conduct a small experiment:

Flutter-generated italic text from Montserrat 48pt Extra-Light Normal
V.S. Montserrat 48pt Extra-Light italic.otf text

They look different! The result shows Flutter can automatically generate some "italic style" text from whatever font it currently has. But that's not necessarily look as the same as the real italic font file that designer created.